# Differences between api and model swagger

Tags: api, swagger

I'm new with swagger and I'm defining an API.

Can I define an api with swagger without needing to use the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation? What exactly is an object model in swagger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can define an API without using the `@ApiModelProperty`. Models object is not a required field in the OpenAPI Spec.

> The Models Object holds a field per model definition, and this is different than the structure of the other objects in the spec. It follows a subset of the JSON-Schema specification.

`@ApiModelProperty` defines the properties of that object. Also Model Object is a part of the response in Swagger

Example you have a model - `User` class.

```
 class User {
   int id;
   String name;
   int age;
 }
```

Model Object will contain information about User.

```
{
"User": {
  "id": "User",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
   "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

`@ApiModelProperty` is used in the Java class `User` to produce this JSON by defining id, name and age inside it.